# Putting a string into a curl command without escape chars

Tags: linux, string, bash, scripting

Ok this might be super obvious but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.
I want to call a curl command from a script with the -d tag to pass some JSON

```
#!/bin/bash
JSON_STR='{"Some":"JSON","Data":"Here"}'
curl -x PUT "http://localhost:port/api/url" -d $JSON_STR
```

Now if I echo the curl command to check to see what it looks like

```
echo curl -x PUT "http://localhost:port/api/url" -d $JSON_STR
```

Everything looks fine:

```
curl -x PUT "http://localhost:port/api/url" -d '{"Some":"JSON","Data":"Here"}'
```

But the API is complaining about the escape char's, its seeing

```
'{\"Some\":\"JSON\",\"Data\":\"Here\"}'
```

Now I understand why they are there (escape chars) but how do I get rid of them in the script command? Is there a raw string in bash?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The man page for `curl` for the `-d` option says that the data is expected to be `"url-encoded"`. Have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by not using JSON_STR and just using the following

```
curl -x PUT "http://localhost:port/api/url" \
    -d '{"Some":"JSON","Data":"'"$VARIABLE"'"}'
```